# Why Form doesn't auto-resize

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have set the `AutoSize` property of the form to True and I have a panel with `Dock` set to `Top`, below my menu and toolbars. I am changing the panel's `Visible` Property to True and False and I expect the form to be resized properly when the panel becomes visible or invisible but this isn't working as expected. What is missing?

Comment: Your code is missing. How are you trying to resize the form? Why should it be resized when the panel is invisible?

Comment: what code? it is one line of code! panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible ;
I have set the autosize property of the form to True, so when the panel is invisible it should resize because it takes less space!

Comment: Try to set the [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode.aspx) property to `GrowAndShrink`.

Comment: @HansPassant: What's wrong with using `Dock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` it will work.